# Improve the user profile merge template when contacting community team

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, merge-accounts

When I use the moderator tool to contact the community team, one of the templates is "user profile merge" (Thanks for adding that btw!)

The template is currently:

```
Hello,

I'm writing in reference to the Code Review Stack Exchange account:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg

I think these profiles belong to the same user and should be merged:

Profile 1: {todo}
Profile 2: {todo}

Regards,  
Simon Forsberg  
Code Review Stack Exchange moderator
```

Which gets rendered as:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to the Code Review Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg
>
> I think these profiles belong to the same user and should be merged:
>
> Profile 1: {todo}
>   Profile 2: {todo}
>
> Regards,
>   Simon Forsberg
>   Code Review Stack Exchange moderator

The biggest problem here is that for some reason "Profile 1" and "Profile 2" are rendered at the same line, so every time I use this template, I add an empty line between Profile 1 and Profile 2 to make it render correctly.

However, when contacting the community team regarding a merge, I've posted one of the accounts already, why would I need to post the same one again in combination with the other one?

I would suggest changing the template to something like:

```
Hello,

I'm writing in reference to the Code Review Stack Exchange account:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg

I think this profile in addition to the profile below belong to the same user and should be merged:

Profile 2: {todo}

Regards,  
Simon Forsberg  
Code Review Stack Exchange moderator
```

Comment: You can also do `[space][space]` (basically, add one space) to add the new line. Also your sock puppet profile link is missing from that post ;-)

Comment: But yeah the first link is annoyingly redundant. Kudos for bringing it up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good call. Starting with the next build, the template will be:

```
Hello,

I'm writing in reference to the Code Review Stack Exchange account:

{profile url}

I think the profile below also belongs to this user and they should be merged:

{todo}

Regards,
{signature}
```