# Can someone fix the 'contact community team' template for underage users?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

I had to escalate a potentially underage user this morning. Two things stuck out to me:

First of all, the current [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355420/369802) says to escalate everything that claims to be less than 16 years old. But when selecting a template, the screen still talks about the old 'under 13 years of age'.  [image: Image showing 'under 13 years of age' text appearing when selecting the underage user template]

Secondly, when I do select the template, all I get is the following text:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to the Meta Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell
>
> {todo}
>
> Regards,
> Tinkeringbell
> Meta Stack Exchange moderator

It would be nice if the template could be more like the ones for [merging accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294636/369802), and would only require us to point out where the claim was made, instead of typing the rest too. (The same actually goes for several of the templates, like the 'suicidal user' template).

Comment: I didn't know that user was underage ...

Comment: I know, I am great at acting like a fully functioning adult! :D Fun fact: Moderators can't even open this on their own profiles, we get the recommendation to use 'contact us'. So this one is clearly fake :P

Comment: Should've tested it on ChrisF's account. He was just pretending to be old all these years ...

Comment: This is seriously confusing when raising flags because the age difference for EU and US is different.

Comment: @bad_coder between you and me I think we don't have a problem if the US gave up their sovereignty and become the 28th member state of the EU ....

Comment: @bad_coder essentially - If you say you're under 16, we escalate it, then the CMs (well the Safety and Trust team) will review and act accordingly. It *is* confusing, so we're expected to highlight, not take action

Comment: @JourneymanGeek good to know because I flag everyone under 16, but I have had such flags declined...(Which is confusing).

Comment: @bad_coder I can imagine not every mod being completely aware that those are the rules now... I wasn't until a CM recently pointed it out to me. Before that I too was still declining flags if the user was older than 13 and didn't seem to be from the EU...

Comment: "From the EU" isn't strictly right either. The UK is not in the EU, but still retains the GDPR laws from when it was.